# MySQL : How to get the sum columns by name of alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query here i got an error the alias says unknown column, whats wrong with this. I need to get the sum of 16_judge_61 , 16_judge_62 , 16_judge_63

```
SELECT s.contestant_number, c.contestant_name, j.judge_name, 

SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id =17 AND s.judge_id =  '61' THEN score END ) AS 16_judge_61, 
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id =17 AND s.judge_id =  '62' THEN score END ) AS 16_judge_62,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id =17 AND s.judge_id =  '63' THEN score END ) AS 16_judge_63,

(16_judge_61 + 16_judge_62 + 16_judge_63) as total //<--here is the problem
 //<--i also tried (sum(16_judge_61) + sum(16_judge_62) + sum(16_judge_63))as total not working as well


FROM tbl_score s INNER JOIN tbl_contestant c ON s.contestant_number = c.contestant_number
INNER JOIN tbl_judges j ON j.judge_id = s.judge_id
WHERE c.gender =  'male'
AND c.con_id = s.con_id
AND j.judge_id =62
GROUP BY s.contestant_number
```

Comment: try removing SUM on case statements then add Sum to (16_judge+.....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is being caused by trying to use an alias in the same `SELECT` clause in which it was defined.  You can't do this, because the alias has not yet been computed.

The knee jerk response to this problem is to just add together the three `CASE` statements for `16_judge_61`, `16_judge_62`, and `16_judge_63`.  But you can improve on this by recognizing that the three conditions can be combined into a single `CASE` statement using `WHERE IN` for the three `judge_id` values.

Try this query:

```
SELECT s.contestant_number,
       c.contestant_name,
       j.judge_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id = 17 AND s.judge_id IN (61,62,63)
                THEN score END ) AS total
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure why you have used SUM(CASE ...)**

```
SELECT s.contestant_number, c.contestant_name, j.judge_name, 

    CASE WHEN s.crit_id =17 AND s.judge_id =  '61' THEN score END  AS 16_judge_61, 
    CASE WHEN s.crit_id =17 AND s.judge_id =  '62' THEN score END  AS 16_judge_62,
    CASE WHEN s.crit_id =17 AND s.judge_id =  '63' THEN score END  AS 16_judge_63,

    SUM(16_judge_61 + 16_judge_62 + 16_judge_63) as total 


    FROM tbl_score s INNER JOIN tbl_contestant c ON s.contestant_number = c.contestant_number
    INNER JOIN tbl_judges j ON j.judge_id = s.judge_id
    WHERE c.gender =  'male'
    AND c.con_id = s.con_id
    AND j.judge_id =62
    GROUP BY s.contestant_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query for that just as following:

```
SELECT *, (16_judge_61+16_judge_62+16_judge_63) AS total FROM (

-------------Your wholequery----------------

) t
```